# What do you think about new website for Network questions?

Tags: feature-request, sister-site

I was posting question on serverfault, and I immediately thought about computer networking questions. Is it good idea to add one more website into league of justice?

Comment: +1 CCNA+/JNCIA+ need their own place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to create your own site: https://stackexchange.com/

Most networking questions can be answered on server fault (administration, advanced) and super user (home, basic). Is there a question that you feel doesn't belong?

Answer (score 3):

Home networking should be right at *home* on SuperUser, and Business networking should be right at home on ServerFault, sometimes less is more :)